# How to draw independent samples from an MCMC output

Tags: bayesian, sampling, autocorrelation, markov-chain-montecarlo

I am using simulated data to compare different multiple imputation methods, one of which uses MCMC.

As I am comparing various methods on simulated data, I will run the algorithm on thousands of datasets in a loop. I hope to draw M approximately independent samples to impute, in a way that is computationally efficient. I plan on running various chains from each of the scenarios to determine what the burnin period needs to be, and then applying the same period to each chain in the loop.

I have three ideas, and wonder which is best, and what others think on the length of the chain required?

1. Sample a long chain for burnin + M*IAT + 1 (Integrated Autocorrelation Time) iterations. Then discard the burnin and sample M draws at random from the remaining iterations.
2. Same as 1, except thinning the chain in some way, for example choosing the 1st, (1 + IAT)th, ..., (1 + M*IAT)th iterations to sample from.
3. Running M independent chains of length burnin + IAT and choosing the final iteration to sample from.

It's worth saying my current estimates are something like:

burnin = ~ 20, IAT = ~ 6, M ranges from 5 to 40 depending on the scenario

Comment: Assuming the burn-in stage is appropriately long, solutions 1 and 2 are similar in spirit with solution 2 being preferred in the literature. The IAT need be estimated properly though and the equivalence with an iid sample of size $M$ need be checked by computing the effective sample size (ESS). Solution 3 is not recommended unless the burn-in time $T_b$ is hugely conservative, as in truth the simulations are from $\mu_0 K^{T_b}$ where $\mu_0$ denotes the starting distribution at time $t=0$ and $K$ is the Markov kernel. There is thus a chance that the resulting sample is biased, if independent.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks! Could you point me to any useful papers? I've been unsuccessful in my search so far.

Comment: Besides books (like [ours](http://amzn.to/2lQDmJR)), the foundational papers by [Geyer](https://projecteuclid.org/accountAjax/Download?downloadType=Journal%20Article&URLID=10.1214%2Fss%2F1177011137&isResultClick=True) and [Gelman and Rubin](https://projecteuclid.org/accountAjax/Download?downloadType=Journal%20Article&URLID=10.1214%2Fss%2F1177011136&isResultClick=True) are likely to discuss this issue.